# Flask is_authenticated user status changes while redirecting to another endpoint

Tags: authentication, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

Im trying to make and endpoint (addurl) which will be only avaliable for logged in users. The problem that occurs is that when Im loggin in on /login endpoint current_user.is_authenticated returns '<bound method User.is_authenticated of <User 2>>' (after login_user(user)). However while redirecting to /addurl current_user.is_authenticated  is somehow overwritten and changes to False. How can i solve this?

CODE

model:

```
from app import db, login_manager


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(1024))



    def is_active(self):
        """True, as all users are active."""
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        """Return the email to satisfy Flask-Login's requirements."""
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        """Return True if the user is authenticated."""
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """False, as anonymous users aren't supported."""
        return False
```

form:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Your Username: ', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Log In')
```

views:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()

        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):

            login_user(user)

            return redirect('/addurl')
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/addurl', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addurl():
    form = CompanyForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            foo()
            return redirect('/base')
    else:
        flash('you have to be logged in')
    return render_template('AddUrl.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to make `addurl` a 'login_required' route. Try something like this:

```
from flask_login import login_required

# original source code...

@app.route('/addurl', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def addurl():
    # original source code...
```

The `@login_required` decorator should do all the magic you need.

Also, be sure to initialize the `LoginManager` correctly in `app.py`:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```